# Can Tableau connect with apache hadoop ? or it should be with only major hadoop distributions?

Tags: hadoop, hive, tableau-api

Need a help on reporting tool Basically we are looking for a best reporting tool that can connect to hive and pull the report. So thought of using Tableau. We are using our own hadoop distribution ( not from hortonworks, cloudera, Mapr Etc). Will tableau connects to apache distribution of hadoop also. If not please suggest some good reporting tool. Freeware is highly recommended.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes tableau will connect with your apache hadoop free distribution.

you will have to put all necessary jar file like hadoop core jars, hadoop common jars into your tableau lib directory. also in your hadoop lib directory you have to put your tableau driver correct version.

then with the help of hiveserver2 also known as hive thrift server. you can give your driver name and connection string

for more details:

http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/connecting-to-hive-server-2-in-secure-mode

http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/administering-hadoop-hive